# Creating custom widget, how to use existing block like "RECENTLY VIEWED PRODUCTS" for a custom block, so that It should support all magento themes

Tags: magento2, module, widget, widgets, recently-viewed

> registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Relabs_LabAPI',
     __DIR__
    );
```

> module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Relabs_LabAPI" setup_version="1.0.2" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> widget.xml

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="sponsored_bestsellerwidget" class="Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller">
        <label translate="true">Bestseller</label>
        <description>Widget in Magento2</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="title" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label>Title</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="description" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true">
                <label>Description</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>

</widgets>
```

> Bestseller.php

```
<?php

namespace Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Bestseller extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList  {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/Bestseller.phtml');
    }
    public function createCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->setPageSize(2) // only get 2 products 
            ->setCurPage(1)  // first page (means limit 0,10)
            ->load(); 
        return $collection->getData();
    }


}
```

> Till here everything is working fine.
>   when I am printing $collection, below is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB01
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [updated_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [price] => 34.0000
            [tax_class_id] => 2
            [final_price] => 34.0000
            [minimal_price] => 34.0000
            [min_price] => 34.0000
            [max_price] => 34.0000
            [tier_price] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 2
            [attribute_set_id] => 15
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => 24-MB04
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [updated_at] => 2018-10-09 06:27:13
            [price] => 32.0000
            [tax_class_id] => 2
            [final_price] => 32.0000
            [minimal_price] => 32.0000
            [min_price] => 32.0000
            [max_price] => 32.0000
            [tier_price] => 
        )

)
```

> widget template(Bestseller.phtml)

```
<?php
  $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller');
  $blockObj->createCollection();
?>
```

> What should I do here so that it can use existing theme block 
>     like "RECENTLY VIEWED ITEMS". I dont want to create custom 
>     html templates, I want to use the theme block template. 
>     Please suggest ???

Answer (score 1):

In Your **`Bestseller.phtml`** File

```
$bestsellerData = [
   'catdata' => $categoryData //get Data in Array
]; 

echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller')->setData($bestsellerData)->setTemplate('categories/bestseller.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Comment: What will be 'Your_Templte_Path'. I didn't get it.

Comment: setTemplate('folder_name/bestseller.phtml')

Comment: Error filtering template: Warning: Illegal offset type in /home/ubuntu/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 76.

Check this link http://magento2.recosenselabs.com

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: <?php $categoryData = $block->createCollection(); $bestsellerData = [ 'catdata' => $categoryData ]; echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Relabs\LabAPI\Block\Widget\Bestseller')->setData($bestsellerData)->setTemplate('widget/Bestseller.phtml')->toHtml(); ?> This is what I am doing in Bestseller.phtml page. Page is not responding for long time and yet not rendered. –